# How do I solve a PDE with a strange boundary condition?

Tags: differential-equations, finite-element-method

How do I solve the PDE with boundary value like this

$$u(t,x,y)=0, \textrm{when } F(x,y)=0$$

using DSolve?

As a specific example, I want to solve heat equation

$$\frac{\partial u}{\partial t}=\alpha\left(\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x^2}+\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial y^2}\right)$$

with a strange boundary condition $u(t,x,y)=0$ where $x^6+y^4=1$. (Or I want to solve it numerically with a strange closed curve.)

Comment: Could you make a specific, concrete example ?

Comment: @b.gatessucks OK,I will edit it.

Comment: Have you tried `NDSolve` for a numerical solution?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

**EDIT** from the author of this answer, 20 March 2016

This old answer was preceding *Mathematica Version 10* which affords *the finite Element Method*. So this answer is now obsolete. See other answers below. The only interesting information that is remaining is that the *Method of lines* associated with the *TensorProductGrid* discretization can eventually handle PDEs in a inhomogeneous medium.

**end of the EDIT**

Here is a solution for your specific example.
I didn' t succeed in finding a more general solution.

The idea is to use `NDSolve`.
  As `NDSolve` accept only rectangular boundary conditions, I take a
rectangular boundary that encloses your domain, 
I make $u(t, x, y) = 
 0$ on this new boundary, and I make the thermal conductivity
between the old and the new boundary very high.

The new problem is therefore of the kind :
Heat equation in a non-homogeneous media with rectangular boundary

After many attempts, 
I succeed in implementing a non-homogeous conductivity
equal to :
-   $\approx1$ if $(x^4 + y^6) < 1$
-  $\gg1$ otherwise

Any improvement would be very appreciated

```
sol = NDSolve[
  With[{thermalConductivity = (1 + (x^4 + y^6)^4)},  
   {(* heat equation *)  
      D[u[x, y, t], t] == 
           D[thermalConductivity * D[u[x, y, t], x], x]  
         + D[thermalConductivity * D[u[x, y, t], y], y],  
    (* boundary conditions *)  
    u[-1.5, y, t] == 0,  
    u[1.5, y, t] == 0,  
    u[x, -1.5, t] == 0,  
    u[x, 1.5, t] == 0,   
    (* initial condition *)  
    u[x, y, 0] == (2 Exp[-8 (x^2 + y^2)] )  
    }],  
  {u},  
  {t, 0, 0.13}, {x, -1.5, 1.5}, {y, -1.5, 1.5},  
  AccuracyGoal -> 2,  
  Method -> {"MethodOfLines",  
    "SpatialDiscretization" -> {  
      "TensorProductGrid",  
      "MinPoints" -> {30, 30}  
      },  
    "TemporalVariable" -> t}]
```

the solution at $t=0.12$ :

```
Plot3D[Evaluate[u[x, y, 0.12] /. sol], {x, -1.5, 1.5}, {y, -1.5, 1.5},
  PlotRange -> {{-1.5, 1.5}, {-1.5, 1.5}, {-.1, .5}},
 MeshFunctions -> {#3 &}, 
 Mesh -> {{0.02, 0.05, 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5}}, PlotPoints -> 30]
```

[image]

The foot of the bump is the shape of $x^4+y^6$, ie the boundary $u(x,y,t)=0$ :

```
ContourPlot[x^4 + y^6 == 1, {x, -1.5, 1.5}, {y, -1.5, 1.5}]
```

[image]

Comment: I'd like this better if you used `Piecewise` for the conductivity (not sure if it works, but worth a try)

Answer (score 36):

After some self-learning of finite element method (FEM), I'm able to write a solver for OP's question without `NDSolve` now. The following code is highly inspired by [ruebenko's excellent answer here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/23885/1871). To understand the code, you must have some basic understanding for FEM, which anyone with a conscience won't say it's trivial 囧. The best introduction for FEM I found so far is in *Chapter 10, Chapter 11, Appendix B* of Olver's *Introduction to Partial Differential Equations*, which is no longer available in his site, but actually Chapter 11 of it still exists as [*Chapter 14* of his lecture notes on *Numerical Analysis*](http://www.math.umn.edu/%7Eolver/num_/lnf.pdf).

The finite element equations for Dirichlet problem of heat conduction equation ($u_t=\alpha  \text{$\Delta $u}+f$ in $\Omega$, $u=g$ on $\partial \Omega$) is as follows:

$$C \frac{d\phi }{dt}+K \phi =P$$
where

$$K_{i j}=\sum _e K_{i j}^e$$
$$C_{i j}=\sum _e C_{i j}^e$$
$$P_i=\sum _e P_{i}^e$$
$$K_{i j}^e=\int _{\Omega ^e}\alpha \left(\frac{\partial N_i}{\partial x}\frac{\partial N_j}{\partial x}+\frac{\partial N_i}{\partial y}\frac{\partial N_j}{\partial y}+\frac{\partial N_i}{\partial z}\frac{\partial N_j}{\partial z}\right)d\Omega$$
$$C_{i j}^e=\int _{\Omega ^e}N_iN_jd\Omega$$
$$P_i^e=\int _{\Omega ^e}fN_id\Omega$$

The first trouble we encountered when implementing FEM in *Mathematica* is how to discretize the whole area and index the elements. Ruebenko did mention [a post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/22244/1871) that gives several pieces of code for meshing, but when writing this answer, what's in my mind is mainly how to make use of existed tools in *Mathematica* as much as possible: does 2D meshing algorithm already integrated in *Mathematica*? Of course! It's used every time we're ploting:

```
Clear["`*"]
grid = RegionPlot[x^6 + y^4 <= 1, {x, -1.5, 1.5}, {y, -1.5, 1.5}(*, PlotPoints -> 100*)] /. 
       {a_, b_, c_, d_} -> Sequence[{a, b, c}, {c, d, a}]; // AbsoluteTiming

coord = First@Cases[grid, GraphicsComplex[a_, __] -> a, Infinity];
index = Flatten[Cases[grid, Polygon[a_] -> a, Infinity], 1];
bound = First@Cases[grid, Line[a__] -> a, Infinity];

grid /. Polygon[a__] -> Sequence[EdgeForm[Black], Polygon[a]]
```

[image]

If you feel confused with this piece of code, just check the `InputForm` of `grid`. (You can check it by selecting the cell `grid` exists and pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd>. )

Then we need to get the stiffness of elements ($K_{i j}^e$). For this part Ruebenko has showed an approach that's smart but somewhat hard to understand and extend to the calculation of $C_{i j}^e$ so I decide to create my own way. The following function is almost a interpretation of the introduction in Olver's lecture note (Though not as good as Ruebenko's, it's also fast :D):

```
w[x_, y_] = a x + b y + c;
wl[{x_, y_}, {{xi_, yi_}, {xj_, yj_}, {xl_, yl_}}] = 
  w[x, y] /. Solve[w[xl, yl] == 1 && w[xi, yi] == 0 && w[xj, yj] == 0, {a, b, c}][[1]];
grad[{{xi_, yi_}, {xj_, yj_}, {xl_, yl_}}] = 
  {D[#, x], D[#, y]} &@ wl[{x, y}, {{xi, yi}, {xj, yj}, {xl, yl}}];

eindex = {i0, i1, i2};
ecoord = {{x0, y0}, {x1, y1}, {x2, y2}};
argu1 = {#, _Integer} & /@ eindex;
argu2 = {#, _Real} & /@ Flatten@ ecoord;
help1 = Tuples[eindex, 2];
allpairs = Map[Join[Complement[ecoord, {#1}], {#1}] &, Tuples[ ecoord, 2], {-2}];
help2 = With[{α = 1}, 
           1/2 Det[{{1, 1, 1}}~Join~Transpose[ecoord]] (α grad[#].grad[#2] &) @@@ allpairs];
getpos = With[{help = help1}, Compile[#, help] &@argu1];
getstiffval = With[{help = help2}, Compile[#, help] &@argu2];
```

Here I stole a function from ruebenko's answer (notice I've made a tiny change):

```
matrixAssembly[rule_, dim_] := 
 Block[{matrix}, 
  System`SetSystemOptions["SparseArrayOptions" -> {"TreatRepeatedEntries" -> 1}];
  matrix = SparseArray[rule, dim];
  System`SetSystemOptions["SparseArrayOptions" -> {"TreatRepeatedEntries" -> 0}];
  matrix]
```

OK, let's assemble the elements and get $K$:

```
coordflattened = Flatten /@ (coord[[#]] & /@ index);
AbsoluteTiming[stiffpos = getpos @@@ index;]
AbsoluteTiming[stiffval = getstiffval @@@ coordflattened;]
AbsoluteTiming[totalstiff = matrixAssembly[Thread[stiffpos -> stiffval], Max@index];]
```

Next part is to get the capacity matrix $C$. The general steps are similar with the building of $K$, but here the calculating of $\int _{\Omega ^e}N_iN_jd\Omega$ turned out to be a little troublesome: at beginning I wanted to make use of the concise syntax of `Integrate` with `Boole` for irregular area, but sadly found it doesn't work for this integration, then I turned to `NIntegrate`, only to find it's a little too slow and the formula for the determination of whether a point is inside a triangle or not [provided by MathWorld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/TriangleInterior.html) is wrong. Finally I had to analyse the integration on a scratch paper and modified the integration into regular forms and turned back to `Integrate`, and the integration didn't finish in an acceptable period of time until I tried different assumptions for times:

```
int = wl[{x, y}, #] wl[{x, y}, #2] & @@@ allpairs;
AbsoluteTiming[
 help3 = With[{ymin = ((y2 - y0) (x - x0))/(x2 - x0) + y0, 
               ymax1 = ((y1 - y0) (x - x0))/(x1 - x0) + y0, 
               ymax2 = ((y2 - y1) (x - x1))/(x2 - x1) + y1}, 
    Simplify[(Abs[
         Integrate[#1, {x, x0, x1}, {y, ymin, ymax1}, Assumptions -> x0 < x1 < x2] + 
         Integrate[#1, {x, x1, x2}, {y, ymin, ymax2},Assumptions -> x0 < x1 < x2]] &) /@ 
      int, (y0 | y1 | y2) ∈ Reals]]]
```

The integration takes about 8 minutes in my computer. This isn't the end: the first and the last output turns out to be wrong! So, please use the following result directly for `help3`:

```
help3 = 
{1/12 Abs[x1 y0 - x2 y0 - x0 y1 + x2 y1 + x0 y2 - x1 y2], 
 1/24 Abs[x1 y0 - x2 y0 - x0 y1 + x2 y1 + x0 y2 - x1 y2], 
 1/24 Abs[x1 y0 - x2 y0 - x0 y1 + x2 y1 + x0 y2 - x1 y2], 
 1/24 Abs[x1 y0 - x2 y0 - x0 y1 + x2 y1 + x0 y2 - x1 y2], 
 1/12 Abs[x1 y0 - x2 y0 - x0 y1 + x2 y1 + x0 y2 - x1 y2], 
 1/24 Abs[x1 y0 - x2 y0 - x0 y1 + x2 y1 + x0 y2 - x1 y2], 
 1/24 Abs[x1 y0 - x2 y0 - x0 y1 + x2 y1 + x0 y2 - x1 y2], 
 1/24 Abs[x1 y0 - x2 y0 - x0 y1 + x2 y1 + x0 y2 - x1 y2], 
 1/12 Abs[x1 y0 - x2 y0 - x0 y1 + x2 y1 + x0 y2 - x1 y2]};
```

> **Remark**
>
> "How do you obtain the correct `help3` above?" It's obtained in *v13.1* with the following code:
>
> ```
> help3 = Integrate[int, {x, y} ∈ Triangle@ecoord] // Simplify
> (* timing: 0.15 second *)
> ```
>
> As we can see, `Integrate` now does a much better job on integration in region.

OK, now let's get $C$:

```
getcapacityval = With[{help = help3}, Compile[#, help] &@argu2];
indexordered = MapThread[#[[#2]] &, {index, Ordering /@ (coord[[#]] & /@ index)}]; 
coordordered = Sort /@ (coord[[#]] & /@ index); 
capacitypos = getpos @@@ indexordered; 
capacityval = getcapacityval @@@ (Flatten /@ coordordered); 
totalcapacity = matrixAssembly[Thread[capacitypos -> capacityval], Max@index];
```

With similar steps, we piecefully get $P$:

```
load[{x_, y_}] =0.;
getload[i_] := Block[{co = coord[[i]]}, 
                     i -> load /@ co Det[{{1, 1, 1}, Sequence @@ Transpose[co]}]/6]
AbsoluteTiming[totalload = matrixAssembly[getload /@ index, Max@index];]
```

The last step is to set the initial condition and boundary condition:

```
ic[{x_, y_}] = Exp[-2 (x^2 + y^2)];
bc = ConstantArray[0., Length@bound];
```

Again, I stole a function from ruebenko's answer (notice the tiny modification):

```
dirichletBoundary[matrix2_, load2_, fPos_List, fValue_List] := 
 Module[{matrix = matrix2, load = load2}, 
        load -= matrix[[All, fPos]].fValue;
        load[[fPos]] = fValue;
        matrix[[All, fPos]] = matrix[[fPos, All]] = 0.;
        matrix += SparseArray[Transpose[{fPos, fPos}] -> Table[1., {Length[fPos]}], 
        Dimensions[matrix], 0]; 
        {matrix, load}]
```

Here I choose backward difference for the discretization of $\frac{d\phi }{dt}$ to avoid possible stability problem:

```
sol = With[{dt = 0.005}, 
    NestList[
     LinearSolve @@ (dirichletBoundary[totalstiff, totalload, bound, bc] +       
     {totalcapacity/dt, #.totalcapacity /dt}) &, ic /@ coord, 25]]; // AbsoluteTiming
```

This step takes 2.462 seconds in my 2GHz laptop with `PlotPoints -> 100` in `RegionPlot` while with same i.c. and time domain andre's solution takes 16.316 seconds <strike>but I won't tell you the code above wastes me almost 20 hours</strike>.

Finally, a demonstration of the fruits:

```
<< Developer`
(* Here I stole the third piece of code from ruebenko. *)
Graphics[GraphicsComplex[coord, Polygon[index], 
  VertexColors -> ToPackedArray@(List @@@ (ColorData["TemperatureMap"][#] & /@ #))]] & /@ sol
Export["my20.gif", %]
ListPlot3D[Flatten /@ Transpose[{coord, #}], PlotRange -> {0, 1}, 
  Mesh -> None, ColorFunctionScaling -> False, ColorFunction -> "TemperatureMap"] & /@ sol
Export["hours.gif", %]
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: nice.  Stay tuned rumor has it FEM capability is coming soon to NDSove...http://reference.wolfram.com/search/?q=fem

Comment: @george2079 Wow, this time it seems to be true! If so, it'll be the best news for me about v10 :D

Comment: Great work. :) Thank you!

Comment: @xzczdYou worked this problem from a robust fundamental theory put forth by Boris Galerkin!! Bad news for the folks at mathematica `;)`.. for you'll put them out of business `;)`!!!  With your permission, I would like to demonstrate your answer to my undergraduate class (that I teach) on FEM.

Comment: @drN Feel free to use it :D

Comment: The current NDSolve FEM capability is limited to linear PDE systems only.

Comment: Can this approach be generalized to : (1) nonlinear PDEs (2) Neumann boundary conditions?

Comment: @LCFactorization Theoretically, it can, but I won't say it's easy. If you just want to solve a PDE with FEM, I'll recommend you to use `NDSolve` in v10, my solution won't surpass it, even when dealing with nonlinear cases. (I guess you've already read e.g. [this post](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/96579/1871).)

Answer (score 20):

Using V10's new FEM functionality, this problem can be solved as follows

```
<< NDSolve`FEM`;
omega = ImplicitRegion[x^6 + y^4 <= 1, {x, y}];
mesh = ToElementMesh[omega, 
  "MaxCellMeasure" -> {"Area" -> 0.005, "Length" -> 0.1}];
gamma = DirichletCondition[u[t, x, y] == 0, x^6 + y^4 == 1];
u = NDSolveValue[
  {Derivative[1, 0, 0][u][t, x, y] == 
   Derivative[0, 0, 2][u][t, x, y] + Derivative[0, 2, 0][u][t, x, y],
   gamma, u[0, x, y] == 1 - (x^6 + y^4)}, u, 
   Element[{x, y}, mesh], {t, 0, 1}]
```

[image]

We can then visualize the solution as follows:

```
pics = Table[
  Quiet[Plot3D[u[t, x, y], {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1},
    MeshFunctions -> ({#3 &}), PlotPoints -> 101, 
    RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y}, x^6 + y^4 <= 1],
    BoundaryStyle -> Thick, ColorFunction -> "TemperatureMap",
    ColorFunctionScaling -> False, PlotRange -> {0, 1.01}]],
  {t, 0, 1, 0.01}];
ListAnimate[pics]
```

[image]

Note that `mesh` is an `ElementMesh` object.  It has some a `"Wireframe"` property that can be accessed directly for visualization.

```
mesh["Wireframe"]
```

[image]

I don't know that there is a simple, built in way to view the plot using the `mesh` directly, but it can be done.

```
elements = #[[1 ;; 3]] & /@ mesh["MeshElements"][[1, 1]];
pts = mesh["Coordinates"];
pts3D[t_] := {#[[1]], #[[2]], u[t, #[[1]], #[[2]]]} & /@ pts
vertexColor[t_Real, k_Integer] := 
  ColorData["TemperatureMap"][u[t, ##] & @@ pts[[k]]];
Graphics3D[GraphicsComplex[pts3D[0.05],
  {Polygon[elements, 
   VertexColors -> Map[vertexColor[0.05, #] &, elements, {2}]]}
 ], PlotRange -> {0, 1}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 13):

I'd like to add to Mark's answer but do not have enough rep to do so in a comment.

One can write:

```
Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"]
omega = ImplicitRegion[x^6 + y^4 <= 1, {x, y}];
m = ToElementMesh[omega];
uif = NDSolveValue[{Derivative[1, 0, 0][u][t, x, y] == 
     Derivative[0, 0, 2][u][t, x, y] + 
      Derivative[0, 2, 0][u][t, x, y], 
    DirichletCondition[u[t, x, y] == 0, True], 
    u[0, x, y] == 1 - (x^6 + y^4)}, u, Element[{x, y}, m], {t, 0, 1}];
```

Note that in the case where the `DirichletCondition` is valid on all of the boundary one can use `True` as the predicate.

If one has already computed a mesh then that can be used within the plotting functions:

```
pics = Table[
   Plot3D[uif[t, x, y], {x, y} \[Element] m, BoundaryStyle -> Thick, 
    ColorFunction -> "TemperatureMap", ColorFunctionScaling -> False, 
    PlotRange -> {0, 1.01}], {t, 0, 1, 0.1}];
ListAnimate[pics]
```

I did not use as many frames.

Comment: Most, welcome...

Comment: How do you handle such cases if the boundary consitions are Neumann type zero boundary conditions on the same region?

Comment: Just remove the `DirichletCondition`. Neumann zero is the default if nothing is specified.