# Optimizing a Numerical Laplace Equation Solver

Tags: differential-equations, numerical-integration, performance-tuning, numerics, finite-element-method

[Laplace's Equation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace%27s_equation) is an equation on a scalar in which, given the value of the scalar on the boundaries (the boundary conditions), one can determine the value of the scalar at any point in the region within the boundaries.

Initially, I considered using `NDSolve`, but I realized that I did not know how to specify the boundary conditions properly. In the example below, my boundary is a square with value 0 along the top, left and right boundary and 1 along the bottom boundary.

Alternatively, the solutions to the equation can be approximated via the [Method of Relaxation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relaxation_%28iterative_method%29). In the method, the region is divided into a grid, with the grid squares along the boundary being assigned (fixed) boundary conditions, and the value for the grid squares within the boundary being iteratively calculated by assigning the average values (in the previous time-step) of four grid squares adjacent to it.

My current code is as follows

```
localmeaner = 
  Mean@{#1[[#2 - 1, #3]], #1[[#2 + 1, #3]], #1[[#2, #3 - 1]], #1[[#2, #3 + 1]]} &;

relaxer = ({#[[1]]}~Join~
     Table[
      {#[[j, 1]]}~Join~
       Table[localmeaner[#, j, i], {i, 2, Dimensions[#][[2]] - 1} ]~
       Join~{#[[j, Dimensions[#][[2]]]]}, {j, 2, 
       Dimensions[#][[1]] - 1}]~Join~{#[[Dimensions[#][[1]]]]}) &;

matrixold = Append[ConstantArray[0, {41, 40}], ConstantArray[1, 40]]; (*test matrix fixing the boundary conditions as 0 on the top, left and right boundaries and 1 on the bottom boundary*)

tempmatrix = Nest[relaxer, matrixold, 300]; (*matrix after 300 relaxations*)
```

`localmeaner` is a function that takes the average of the four grid squares adjacent to a square.

`relaxer` is a function that preserves the boundary values but otherwise applies `localmeaner` onto each of the grid cells to produce their new values based on the average of the four grid cells adjacent to it.

> Is there a quicker way to find a numerical solution to the Laplace's Equation given specific boundary conditions?

As a point of interest, one can plot the solution as `ArrayPlot[tempmatrix*1., ColorFunction -> "Rainbow"]`, resulting in the following image, which helps one to visualize the results.

[image]

NB: I'm planning to extend this solution to approximations that can work in polar coordinates, Cartesian coordinates in three dimensions and spherical coordinates, so I'm hoping that the answers could be equally general.

Comment: Take a look [here](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/NDSolvePDE.html).

Comment: Too bad! So since the documentation states that "This rules out purely elliptic equations such as Laplace's equation, but leaves a large class of evolution equations that can be solved quite efficiently.", I'd have to continue to work using my method?

Comment: I posted a pretty flexible relaxation solver for the Poisson equation [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/11768/245). The Laplace equation is a special case of that. Maybe you can use it for your problem.

Comment: @Jens thank you! have you ever tried to write code that works for the Poisson equation in three dimensions, in particular in spherical coordinates? I was hoping that I could modify your code to do so, but haven't figured out a way yet.

Comment: I haven't extended it to three dimensions. The first thing one might try is to do a cylindrically symmetric 3D problem in cylinder coordinates, where the radial derivative is modified to $\frac{1}{r}\frac{\partial}{\partial r}\left(r\,\frac{\partial f}{\partial r}\right)$ but can still be discretized. But fully 3D calculations aren't just tricky, they may quickly become impractical for *Mathematica*. It depends on the application, I guess, but I'd go straight to FORTRAN.

Comment: What you consider optimization also depends on what limits you in any particular application: memory or speed...

Comment: @Jens how are the calculations likely to become impractical? do you mean that they would take up too much memory, or that they would be far too slow? by the way, the actual boundary condition for the final problem that I'd like to solve is a http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_cap.

Comment: Oh yes, that should be doable in *Mathematica*. I was more thinking about a really big electrostatic problem (as in the many components of a particle accelerators on the large-scale side, or molecular fields on the small-scale end of the spectrum). But I've only needed the 2D Cartesian version so far.

Comment: I see! If I work something out, I guess I'll post it up here then. Perhaps I should take a look at FORTRAN too.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Here is a code that is about 2 orders of magnitude faster. We will use a finite element method to solve the issue at hand. Before we start, note however, that the transition between the Dirichlet values should be smooth.

We use the finite element method because that works for general domains and some meshing utilities exist [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/22244/creating-a-2d-meshing-algorithm-in-mathematica) and in the links there in. For 3D you can use the build in [TetGenLink](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/TetGenLink/tutorial/Overview.html).

For your rectangular domain, we just create the coordinates and incidences by hand:

```
<< Developer`
nx = ny = 4;
coordinates = 
  Flatten[Table[{i, j}, {i, 0., 1., 1/(ny - 1)}, {j, 0., 1., 
     1/(nx - 1)}], 1];
incidents = 
  Flatten[Table[{j*nx + i, 
     j*nx + i + 1, (j - 1)*nx + i + 1, (j - 1)*nx + i}, {i, 1, 
     nx - 1}, {j, 1, ny - 1}], 1];

(* triangulate the quad incidences *)
incidents = 
  ToPackedArray[
   incidents /. {i1_?NumericQ, i2_, i3_, i4_} :> 
     Sequence[{i1, i2, i3}, {i3, i4, i1}]];

Graphics[GraphicsComplex[
  coordinates, {EdgeForm[Gray], FaceForm[], Polygon[incidents]}]]
```

[image]

Now, we create the finite element symbolically and compile that:

```
tmp = Join[ {{1, 1, 1}}, 
   Transpose[Quiet[Array[Part[var, ##] &, {3, 2}]]]];
me = {{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {0, 1}};
p = Inverse[tmp].me;
help = Transpose[ (p.Transpose[p])*Abs[Det[tmp]]/2];

diffusion2D = 
  With[{code = help}, 
   Compile[{{coords, _Real, 2}, {incidents, _Integer, 1}}, Block[{var},
     var = coords[[incidents]];
     code
     ]
    , RuntimeAttributes -> Listable
    (*,CompilationTarget\[Rule]"C"*)]];

AbsoluteTiming[allElements = diffusion2D[coordinates, incidents];]
```

You can not do this in FORTRAN! For this specific problem the element contributions are all the same, so that could be utilized, but since you wanted a somewhat more general approach I am leaving it as it is.

To assemble the elements into a system matrix:

```
matrixAssembly[ values_, pos_, dim_] := Block[{matrix, p},
  System`SetSystemOptions[ 
   "SparseArrayOptions" -> {"TreatRepeatedEntries" -> 1}];
  matrix = SparseArray[ pos -> Flatten[ values], dim];
  System`SetSystemOptions[ 
   "SparseArrayOptions" -> {"TreatRepeatedEntries" -> 0}];
  Return[ matrix]]

pos = Compile[{{inci, _Integer, 2}}, 
    Flatten[Map[Outer[List, #, #] &, inci], 2]][incidents];

dofs = Max[pos];

AbsoluteTiming[
 stiffness = matrixAssembly[ allElements, pos, dofs] ]
```

The last part that is missing are the Dirichlet conditions. We modify the system matrix in place for that:

```
SetAttributes[dirichletBoundary, HoldFirst]
dirichletBoundary[ {load_, matrix_}, fPos_List, fValue_List] := 
 Block[{},
  load -= matrix[[All, fPos]].fValue;
  load[[fPos]] = fValue;
  matrix[[All, fPos]] = matrix[[fPos, All]] = 0.;
  matrix += SparseArray[ 
    Transpose[ {fPos, fPos}] -> Table[ 1., {Length[fPos]}], 
    Dimensions[matrix], 0];
  ]

load = Table[ 0., {dofs}];
diriPos1 = Position[coordinates, {_, 0.}];
diriVals1 = Table[1., {Length[diriPos1]}];
diriPos2 = 
  Position[coordinates, ({_, 
      1.} | {1., _?(# > 0 &)} | {0., _?(# > 0 &)})];
diriVals2 = Table[0., {Length[diriPos2]}];
diriPos = Flatten[Join[diriPos1, diriPos2]];
diriVals = Join[diriVals1, diriVals2];
dirichletBoundary[{load, stiffness}, diriPos, diriVals]
AbsoluteTiming[ 
 solution = LinearSolve[ stiffness, load(*, Method\[Rule]"Krylov"*)]; ]
```

When I use your code on my laptop it has about 1600 quads and takes about 6 seconds. When I run this code with `nx = ny = 90;` (which gives about 16000 triangles) it runs in about 0.05 seconds. Note that the element computation and matrix assembly take less time than the `LinearSolve`. That's the way things should be. The result can be visualized:

```
Graphics[GraphicsComplex[coordinates, Polygon[incidents], 
  VertexColors -> 
   ToPackedArray@(List @@@ (ColorData["Rainbow"][#] & /@ 
        solution))]]
```

[image]

For the 3D case have a look [here](http://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/Conferences/7549/).

Hope this helps.

Comment: There are so many nice tricks in here... (+1). To make this code easier to study, I think it will be good to add a link to this page: [What are some useful, undocumented Mathematica functions?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/805/245)

Comment: @Jens, I am glad you like it.

Comment: @ruebenko this is great! I was looking through some of the documentation for other Laplace / Poisson equation solvers on the Mathematica site but was having trouble understanding them. Thank you for taking the time to explain your solution in detail.

Comment: By the way, just out of curiosity, did you already have a solution to this problem before or did you code this from scratch?

Comment: @VincentTjeng, well I had the 3D version from a talk I gave and then had some other notebooks with experiments. Also, I worked a lot with FEM during my [thesis](http://www.freidok.uni-freiburg.de/volltexte/6440/). You may also want to read [this](http://www.math.hu-berlin.de/~cc/download/public/software/documentation/acf.pdf).

Comment: @VincentTjeng, the above code has the limitation that the diffusion coefficient is fixed, but it's not that much more work to make it variable, but the approach would be slightly different.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. When you say M-, are you referring to MATLAB? Also, what do you mean by the diffusion coefficient? When I Google those two terms, I get results which I'm quite sure are not what you meant.

Comment: @VincentTjeng, Mathematica provides a unique environment for numerics. The libraries are fast, plus you have the advantage that you can do symbolic pre-processing. This, in a nutshell, gives unique capabilities.

Comment: @VincentTjeng, what you have here is "Div[Grad[u]]" which is the Laplacian. I was talking about "Div[f.Grad[u]]" where f is function of space. In the Laplacian case in 2D f= {{1,0},{0,1}}

Answer (score 5):

We all know FEM has been implemented in `NDSolve` since *v10* and solving Laplace equation with *Mathematica* is no longer a problem. Still, I'd like to post this answer solving Laplace equation with FDM, as an illustration for the usage of `pdetoae` (a function that discretizes differential equations to algebraic equations, its definition can be found [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/127997/1871)).

```
xpoints = 90;
ypoints = 90;
{xl, xr} = xdomain = {0, 1};
{yl, yr} = ydomain = {0, 1};
xgrid = Array[# &, xpoints, xdomain];
ygrid = Array[# &, ypoints, ydomain];
difforder = 2;

eqn = D[u[x, y], {x, 2}] + D[u[x, y], {y, 2}] == 0;
bc = {u[xl, y] == 0, u[xr, y] == 0, u[x, yl] == 1, u[x, yr] == 0};

var = Flatten@Outer[u, xgrid, ygrid];

(* Definition of pdetoae isn't included in this code piece,
   please find it in the link above *)
ptoa = pdetoae[u[x, y], {xgrid, ygrid}, difforder];
del = Delete[#, {{1}, {-1}}] &;

ae = del /@ del@ptoa@eqn; // AbsoluteTiming
bcae = MapAt[del, ptoa@bc, {{1}, {2}}];

{b, mat} = CoefficientArrays[{ae, bcae} // Flatten, var]; // AbsoluteTiming
sollst = LinearSolve[N@mat, -b]; // AbsoluteTiming

sol = ListInterpolation[ArrayReshape[sollst, {xpoints, ypoints}], {xgrid, ygrid}];

Plot3D[sol[x, y], {x, xl, xr}, {y, yl, yr}, ColorFunction -> "Rainbow"]

(* {0.331821, Null} *)
(* {0.100300, Null} *)
(* {0.081133, Null} *)
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

This method is no more than half as fast as [user21](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/18437/user21)'s method above, but easier to extend to "polar coordinates, Cartesian coordinates in three dimensions and spherical coordinates". We can also easily obtain a solution with higher accuracy by raising the difference order i.e. `difforder`. Of course all these self-implementations aren't necessary nowadays :) .

Comment: @ xzczd : Sorry, it cannot be reproduced on my comp https://www.dropbox.com/s/vz15ubuam6nkaeu/Dirichlet.pdf?dl=0

Comment: @user64494 As mentioned in the answer, this solution uses the function `pdetoae`, its definition can be found in the link above.