# Implementation of MATLAB's "numgrid" function

Tags: list-manipulation, sparse-arrays, matlab

I am looking for an implementation of MATLAB's [`numgrid`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/finite-difference-laplacian.html) function, in particular the "B" mode.

For example, I want to get the matrix corresponding to the following matrix in MATLAB:

```matlab
numgrid('B', 80)
```

Comment: 1. More information is needed. The linked page doesn't involve enough details about `numgrid` (and it's a bit surprising to me there doesn't seem to be a stand-alone document page for `numgrid`! ), according to [this page](http://math.aalto.fi/opetus/osdylask/pre2003/H99/ideointia.html),  `'B'` stands for _exterior of a "Butterfly"_, then how is the butterfly defined? 2. Somewhat related: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/43039/1871 3. Are you aware that it's not good idea to use `For` and `AppendTo` in _Mathematica_?: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/134609/1871

Comment: The laziness is astounding.  You include a couple of links I'm supposed to follow to figure out what this function does (I did not follow the links) when you should have described plainly what it does.  Then you include a screenshot from some textbook that is - I guess - related to your problem, with a couple of pieces highlighted that in no way describe your problem.

Comment: @JasonB. sorry if this wasted your time. I sometimes start questions as placeholders for problems whose solutions  would benefit the wider community, and come back later to fill in the results. The community can be quite good at mind reading :)

Comment: Well, I don't think it's good idea. Surely the community is kind. Finally there come 3 answers for an (currently) unclear question! But kindness is non-renewable.

Comment: @xzczd Those are good answers. Having multiple implementations is good robustness check. Chances are someone else will need the `numgrid` function, quite a few textbooks reference it

Comment: It would be great if someone rewrote the question now that it has answers, future readers would surely appreciate clarity.

Comment: So did you verify your SOR implementation?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The source code of some of the MATLAB functions is available to its users. In this example, if you type `edit numgrid`, its file will be open, and to my surprise, it wasn't very complicated, so I decided to rewrite it with Mathematica's built-in functions (I'm sure there is room for improvement).

###### Update

Thanks to @chyanog's suggestion to remove `Thread` in building `SparseArray`, it performs almost 3 times faster.

```
ClearAll[NumGridB];

NumGridB[n_Integer] :=
 Block[{x = ConstantArray[Subdivide[-1., 1, n - 1], n], y, t, r, temp,
    Indeterminate = 0.},

  y = Transpose[x[[All, -1 ;; 1 ;; -1]]];

  t = Quiet@ArcTan[x, y];
  r = Sqrt[x^2 + y^2];

  temp = SparseArray[
   1 - Unitize[
     UnitStep[
       r - (Sin[2 t] + 0.2*Sin[8 t])] + (1 -
        UnitStep[Abs[x] - 1]) + (1 - UnitStep[Abs[y] - 1]) - 3]];

  SparseArray[
 SortBy[temp["ExplicitPositions"], Last] ->
  Range[temp["ExplicitLength"]], {n, n}, 0]
  ]
```

Notes:

- I used the same variable names as MATLAB, except `temp`, so you can follow its logic.
- In `Block` scope, I used `Indeterminate=0.` with `Quiet` because in Mathematica `ArcTan[0, 0]` returns `Indeterminate` with a `Message`, but in MATLAB, `atan2` simply return `0` - @chyanog suggests using `Arg[x+I*y]`, but since it's a little slower, I decided not to use it.

#### Example:

Mathematica:

```
ArrayPlot[NumGridB[7], Frame -> False]
```

MATLAB:

```matlab
imagesc(numgrid('B',7))
```

[image: comparison]

Higher number (`n=500`):

[image: comparison]

#### Speed

| n | MATLAB (second - `tic;toc;`) | Mathematica (second - `RepeatedTiming`) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 500 | 0.006 | <s>0.18</s> 0.044 |
| 5000 | 0.55 | <s>17.9</s> 4.75 |

Without touching `*Compile`, for not large `n`, its timing is reasonable. If you did improve the speed, feel free to post it here.

#### Update 2

Other answers show clearly compiling will further boost the performance. I decide to use the [`wolfram-library-link-rs`](https://github.com/WolframResearch/wolfram-library-link-rs) crate to use [Rust](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rust_%28programming_language%29) for building a LibraryLink library.

You can get the code and compiled library from [this GitHub page](https://github.com/ben-izd/numgrid).

At first glance, it wasn't much faster than others (clearly slower than @chyanog solution!), but if you open [Task Manager](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Task_Manager_(Windows)) while running MATLAB `numgrid`, you'll notice is not a single-threaded command, So this became an opportunity to leverage Rust's power in multithreading to set a new record.

After downloading the *.dll* file from the [Release Section](https://github.com/ben-izd/numgrid/releases/tag/Main) of the GitHub page, execute the following command and you're good to go:

```
(* Single-threaded *)
NumGridBCompiled =
 LibraryFunctionLoad[
  "C:\\numgrid.dll", "numgrid_b", {Integer},
  LibraryDataType["NumericArray", "UnsignedInteger32", 2]]


(* Multi-threaded *)
NumGridBParallelCompiled =
 LibraryFunctionLoad[
  "C:\\numgrid.dll",
  "numgrid_b_parallel", {Integer},
  LibraryDataType["NumericArray", "UnsignedInteger32", 2]]
```

#### Benchmark

##### Speed

[image: benchmark comparison]

- For "Ben Izd", AbsoluteTiming was used.

Table (all the timings are in seconds):

| n | MATLAB | NumGridBParallelCompiled | NumGridBCompiled | chyanog | xzczd | Ben Izd |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1,000 | 0.023 | **0.0039** | 0.033 | 0.016 | 0.061 | 0.16 |
| 5,000 | 0.61 | **0.25** | 0.84 | 0.63 | 1.49 | 4.72 |
| 10,000 | 2.4 | **1.47** | 3.39 | 2.06 | 5.98 | 46.1 |

##### Memory

Although I'm not fully aware of Mathematica accuracy on LibraryLink calls, here is the plot:

[image: memory consumption]

Table (all the sizes are in bytes):

| n | MATLAB | NumGridBParallelCompiled | NumGridBCompiled | chyanog | xzczd | Ben Izd |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1,000 | 7,864,000 | **4,000,256** | 4,000,256 | 24,020,064 | 16,000,432 | 95,388,352 |
| 5,000 | 195,764,000 | **100,000,256** | 100,000,256 | 600,085,664 | 400,000,432 | 2,390,195,048 |
| 10,000 | 782,712,000 | **400,000,256** | 400,000,256 | 2,400,163,872 | 1,600,000,432 | 9,563,573,936 |

Notes:

- MATLAB timings were based on multiple `tic;toc;` and I try a slightly different size and the timings were around the same number.
- MATLAB  memory usage was based on its profiler with `profile('-memory','on')`, and its `Peak Memory` (values were in `Kb`, so it was converted accordingly)
- MATLAB version is 9.12.0 (2022b update 2), Mathematica 13.1.0, and system is AMD [Ryzen 3950X](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Table_of_AMD_processors)

Comment: `Thread` is unnecessary here and inefficient, you can also use `Arg[x+I*y]` instead of `Arctan`, it will not have a warnings.

Comment: @chyanog I really appreciate your comment (~3x times faster). Thank you.

Comment: As to the MATLAB timing, have you taken [the influence of memory pre-allocation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70531631/1551513) into account? Are the timings obtained on first run?

Comment: @BenIzd It's my pleasure.

Comment: Amazing excavation, thanks!

Comment: @xzczd I hope I answered your questions in update 2.

Answer (score 12):

After searching for a while I found the source code of `numgrid` [here](https://github.com/nim65s/N7/blob/master/be/ana_num_2A/numgrid.m). So, here's my trial with `FunctionCompile`:

```
bfnumgrid =
   FunctionCompile@
    Function[Typed[n, "Real64"], 
     With[{atan2 = {y, x} |-> If[x == 0 && y == 0, 0., ArcTan[x, y]], 
           sqrt = Sqrt, sin = Sin}, 
       Module[{t, r, i = 1},
         Table[t = atan2[y, x];
               r = sqrt@(x^2 + y^2); 
               If[r >= (sin@(2*t) + .2*sin@(8*t)) && -1 < x < 1 && -1 < y < 1, 
                  i++, 0], 
               {x, -1, 1, 2/(n - 1)}, 
               {y, 1, -1, -2/(n - 1)}]\[Transpose]]]]; // AbsoluteTiming
(* {9.24076, Null} *)

bfshape[5000]; // AbsoluteTiming
(* {1.57289, Null} *)
```

Be careful with the subtle differences between MATLAB and *Mathematica* e.g. [`atan2`](https://jp.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/atan2.html) v.s. `ArcTan`, [row-major v.s. column-major](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/10582/1871), etc. I don't choose the `Arg` trick [shown by chyanog](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/270516/implementation-of-matlabs-numgrid-function/270520#comment675170_270520) because it turns out to be a little slower compared with the `If[…]` work-around in my current implementation.

For comparison, [Ben lzd's solution](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/270520/1871) takes about 6.55 s on my laptop for `n == 5000`.

Visualization:

```
ArrayPlot[bfnumgrid[500], ColorFunction -> "AvocadoColors"]
```

[image]

Answer (score 12):

```
Clear[cf, numGridB];
cf = Compile[{{n, _Integer}, x, {range, _Real, 1}},
   Table[With[{r = Sqrt[x^2 + y^2], t = Arg[x + I y]},
     Boole[r >= Sin[2 t] + 0.2*Sin[8 t] && Abs@x < 1 && Abs@y < 1]], {y, range}
    ], RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable}, RuntimeOptions -> "Speed", 
       CompilationTarget -> "C"
   ];

numGridB[n_] :=
  With[{range = Range[-1., 1, 2/(n - 1)]},
    Transpose@ArrayReshape[# Accumulate@#, {n, n}] &@Flatten@cf[n, -range, range]
   ];

numGridB[10] // MatrixForm
numGridB[5000]; // RepeatedTiming
```

`$Version`

> 13.1.0 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (June 16, 2022)

For GCC (mingw-w64) compiler, there is no significant difference between `-O2, -O3, -Ofast` flag

> {0.840892, Null}

For VC compiler, `/O2`  flag

> {0.596376, Null}

For Clang compiler, same flag as GCC

> {0.561526, Null}

Compared with MATLAB
[image: MATLAB screenshot]

Another implementation:

```
Clear[numGridB2];
numGridB2 = Compile[{{n, _Integer}},
   Module[{x, y, t, r, bin, tol = 2.*^-16},
    y = ConstantArray[Range[-1., 1, 2/(n - 1)], n];
    x = -Transpose[y];
    t = ArcTan[x + tol, y];
    r = Sqrt[x^2 + y^2];
    bin = Flatten@BitAnd[UnitStep[r - (Sin[2 t] + 0.2*Sin[8 t])], 
       UnitStep[1 - tol - Abs@x], UnitStep[1 - tol - Abs@y]];
    Transpose@Partition[bin Accumulate@bin, n]
    ]];

numGridB2[10] // Grid
numGridB2[5000]; // RepeatedTiming
```

> {0.980508, Null}

Comment: So this is faster than matlab in MSVC case? Why gcc is much slower?

Comment: What compiler flags were used? Was it compiled with different optimisation flags?

Answer (score 7):

This is a little slower than Ben's version, but I thought I'd share this anyway since the `"ExplicitLength"` and `"ExplicitPositions"` properties are not known to earlier versions, and I wanted to show off the use of `CoordinateBoundsArray[]`:

```
numGridB[n_Integer?Positive] := Module[{pos, t, temp, x, y},
   {x, y} = Transpose[CoordinateBoundsArray[{{-1., 1.}, {-1., 1.}},
                                            {Into[n - 1], Into[n - 1]}],
                      {3, 2, 1}];
   y = Reverse[y]; t = ArcTan[x + $MachineEpsilon, y];
   temp = SparseArray[1 - Unitize[UnitStep[Sqrt[x^2 + y^2] -
                                           (Sin[2 t] + 0.2*Sin[8 t])] -
                      UnitStep[Abs[x] - 1] - UnitStep[Abs[y] - 1] - 1]];
   pos = temp["NonzeroPositions"];
   SparseArray[SortBy[pos, Last] -> Range[Length[pos]], {n, n}, 0]]
```

For visualization purposes, let me include this as well:

```
(* https://tpfto.wordpress.com/2019/04/17/faking-a-birds-colors-and-miscellanea/ *)
birdie[x_?NumericQ] /; 0 <= x <= 1 := 
Blend[{RGBColor[0.242, 0.15, 0.66], RGBColor[0.27, 0.2135, 0.83], 
       RGBColor[0.281, 0.298, 0.939], RGBColor[0.271, 0.385, 0.99], 
       RGBColor[0.202, 0.479, 0.99], RGBColor[0.172, 0.564, 0.94], 
       RGBColor[0.13, 0.639, 0.892], RGBColor[0.048, 0.7025, 0.827], 
       RGBColor[0.07, 0.746, 0.726], RGBColor[0.203, 0.78, 0.61], 
       RGBColor[0.36, 0.8, 0.463], RGBColor[0.58, 0.79, 0.29], 
       RGBColor[0.786, 0.757, 0.16], RGBColor[0.946, 0.7285, 0.217], 
       RGBColor[0.995, 0.79, 0.2], RGBColor[0.961, 0.891, 0.153], 
       RGBColor[0.977, 0.984, 0.08]}, x]
```

and then, we have

```
ArrayPlot[numGridB[7], ColorFunction -> birdie, Frame -> False]
```

[image: numgrid visualization]

```
ArrayPlot[numGridB[500], ColorFunction -> birdie, Frame -> False]
```

[image: numgrid visualization, higher resolution]

---

**Edit 7/10/2022**

The stuff above was written a little before I went to bed. Now with the benefit of getting sleep and seeing Ben's comment and chyanog's new answer, I came up with the following:

```
numGridB[n_Integer?Positive] := Module[{pos, sgn2, temp, zz},
   zz = {1, I} . Transpose[CoordinateBoundsArray[{{-1., 1.}, {1., -1.}},
                                                 {Into[n - 1], Into[n - 1]}], {3, 2, 1}];
   sgn2 = Sign[zz]^2;
   temp = SparseArray[BitOr[1 - UnitStep[Abs[zz] - Im[sgn2 (1 + 0.2 sgn2^3)]],
                            UnitStep[Abs[Re[zz]] - 1], UnitStep[Abs[Im[zz]] - 1]],
                      Automatic, 1];
   pos = temp["NonzeroPositions"];
   SparseArray[SortBy[pos, Last] -> Range[Length[pos]], {n, n}, 0]]
```

How this version works is an exercise I will leave for the interested.

Comment: No matter how hard we push, there is always room for improvement. I really appreciate your answer.

Comment: (one small point, wouldn't `{1., -1.}` be better than `Reverse[y]`?)

Comment: Thanks @Ben, that certainly streamlined the new version I came up with a little after waking up. ;)