# Writing compiled functions as fast as Python's Numba

Tags: performance-tuning, compile, simulation

I want to write some code to simulate a damped oscillator that is just as fast as code written using Numba's `@njit` decorator. I've written the mathematica code and mine is 20-40x slower than the python code written by YouTuber Jack of Some.

Here is the code from Jack of Some's video on [speeding up Python code with Numba](https://youtu.be/x58W9A2lnQc); I've changed it a bit to run in just one jupyter cell:

```
import numpy as np
from numba import jit, njit, types, vectorize

@njit
def friction_fn(v, vt):
    if v > vt:
        return - v * 3
    else:
        return - vt * 3 * np.sign(v)

@njit
def simulate_spring_mass_funky_damper(x0, T=10, dt=0.0001, vt=1.0):
    times = np.arange(0, T, dt)
    positions = np.zeros_like(times)

    v = 0
    a = 0
    x = x0
    positions[0] = x0/x0

    for ii in range(len(times)):
        if ii == 0:
            continue
        t = times[ii]
        a = friction_fn(v, vt) - 100*x
        v = v + a*dt
        x = x + v*dt
        positions[ii] = x/x0
    return times, positions

_ = simulate_spring_mass_funky_damper(0.1)

%time _ = simulate_spring_mass_funky_damper(0.1)
```

The output is

```
CPU times: user 1.38 ms, sys: 337 µs, total: 1.72 ms
Wall time: 1.72 ms
```

vs my Mathematica code

```
ClearAll[friction, simulateSpring, jacksSpring];

friction = Compile[{{v, _Real}, {vt, _Real}},
   If[v > vt,
        -v*3.0,
        -vt*3.0*Sign[v]]
   ];

simulateSpring = 
  Compile[{{x0, _Real}, {t, _Real}, {dt, _Real}, {vt, _Real}},
   
   Module[{τ, times, positions, v = 0.0, a = 0.0, x = x0},
    
    τ = t;
    times = Range[0.0, t, dt];
    positions = ConstantArray[0.0, Length@times];
    positions[[1]] = x0/x0;
    
    Do[
        τ = times[[i]];
        a = friction[v, vt] - 100*x;
        v = v + a*dt;
        x = x + v*dt;
        positions[[i]] = x/x0;
     ,
     {i, 2, Length@times}];
    {times, positions}
    ]
   ];
jacksSpring[x_] := simulateSpring[x, 10.0, 0.0001, 1.0];

Print["CPU time: ", Timing[jacksSpring[0.1]][[1]]*1000, " ms"]
```

from which we have

```
CPU time: 27.703 ms
```

Comment: I think it may be `AbsoluteTiming` that you want, not `Timing`.

Comment: Right, or RepatedTiming.
And with adding `SetOptions[Compile, CompilationTarget->"C" ,RuntimeOptions->"Speed"]` I get AbsoluteTiming down to about 3 ms, on Windows.

Comment: Thanks! Yes, this helps substantially and I get now `2.639 ms` on my machine. I'm still interested if anyone has any ideas to beat the python attempt, especially if they can rewrite the code in a more idiomatic fashion.

Comment: Maybe someone could try the newer `FunctionCompile`. Though probably it will be slower than `Compile`.

Comment: Why do you need this? If Python runs fine, just use Python.

Comment: ^ Agree with Rolf, if it works fine in python, you can also call python from Mathematica.

Comment: @RolfMertig I am about to set out on writing a package for scientific computations and I'd like to better understand the numerical capabilities of Mathematica. I think the end product will be cleaner if it is feasible to keep it all in one language.

By the way, thank you for FeynCalc-- it really helped me out in my QFT courses.

Comment: I checked out `FunctionCompile`, and the results were so close as to not be worth it on my machine (~6.1ms with Compile and the options above, ~6.2ms with FunctionCompile). I had to wrap `Range` in a `KernelFunction` as the built-in Native\`Range does not support Real arguments, but since that's only called once I would be surprised if that were the bottleneck. Is there some way to replace the `Do` with some matrix maths?

Comment: One thing that’s not clear to me is whether the Numba timing includes the compilation, because when used with Jupyter it is much faster on subsequent evaluations, presumably because of caching.

Comment: @C.E. I’m not a python pro but my understanding is that the code provided already runs the function once to compile and then times the second run. Without this, the timing scheme will include the compilation time.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Based on the experience obtained [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/132130/1871):

```
friction = Compile[{{v, _Real}, {vt, _Real}}, If[v > vt, -v*3.0, -vt*3.0*Sign[v]]];

simulateSpring = 
  Compile[{{x0, _Real}, {t, _Real}, {dt, _Real}, {vt, _Real}}, 
   Module[{τ, times, positions, v = 0.0, a = 0.0, x = x0}, τ = t;
    times = Range[0.0, t, dt];
    positions = Table[0.0, {Length@times}];
    positions[[1]] = x0/x0;
    Do[τ = times[[i]];
     a = friction[v, vt] - 100*x;
     v = v + a*dt;
     x = x + v*dt;
     positions[[i]] = x/x0;, {i, 2, Length@times}];
    {times, positions}], RuntimeOptions -> Speed, CompilationTarget -> C, 
   CompilationOptions -> {InlineExternalDefinitions -> True, 
     InlineCompiledFunctions -> True}];

lib = simulateSpring[[-1]]

Print["CPU time: ", RepeatedTiming[lib[0.1, 10.0, 0.0001, 1.0]][[1]]*1000, " ms"]
```

> ```
> CPU time: 1.6 ms
> ```

Compiled with *TDM GCC 5.1.0-2 64bit*, `"SystemCompileOptions"->"-Ofast"`.

`RepeatedTiming` of the original `jacksSpring[0.1]` is 20 ms here. I tried timing the python code but failed. (Seems that Numba is not configured correctly on my laptop, the timing is about 0.35 s. )

Comment: I'm surprised it even works to write `RuntimeOptions -> Speed` and `CompilationTarget -> C`, usually they're written `"Speed"` and `"C"`. Nevertheless, I tried this and it gives me  1.26 both with and without quotation marks, whereas Numba gives me 1.23 ms. So it's very close. +1

Comment: @C.E. String options and option values of `Compile` don't need to be string, so do those of `NDSolve`, AFAIK. (But properties of `FittedModel` and methods of `InterpolatingFunction` need to be string. )

Comment: @xzczd  great! Can we apply this method for PDEs (FEM) in MMA?

Comment: @ABCDEMMM If you mean FEM built in `NDSolve`, then high level functions like `NDSolve` already makes use of `Compile` internally AFAIK; if you mean self implementation of FEM, just search in this site, you'll see most (if not all) of the answers implementing FEM in a low level way makes use of `Compile`, [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/23885/1871) is an example.

Comment: @xzczd  it means that if we use build-in NDSolve, every simulation will run directly in c-code?

Comment: @ABCDEMMM No, but `NDSolve` is already optimized with various techniques, including but not limited to `Compile`. BTW, if you're expecting to use `Compile` **on** `NDSolve`, it's impossible, because `Compile` can handle only a small part of functions, for more info check this: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1096/1871