# SmoothDensityHistogram hiding data structure

Tags: plotting, probability-or-statistics

I have data which shows very clear structure in a `ListPlot`.

```
xf = Import["https://pastebin.com/raw/r5Aiq03E", "List"];
zf = Import["https://pastebin.com/raw/7bvzMuQV", "List"];

a0 = 5.29177*^-11; λ = 800*^-9/a0;
V2aGrid = Partition[Riffle[zf/λ, xf/λ], 2]; v2a = {{33, 37}, {-2, 2}};

ListPlot[V2aGrid, ImageSize -> Large, PlotRange -> v2a]
```

[image: ListPlot]

However, when I try to represent this data with `SmoothDensityHistogram`, the structure is hidden.  Having used:

```
 SmoothDensityHistogram[V2aGrid, Automatic, "PDF", ColorFunction->
 "AvocadoColors", PlotRangePadding->None, PlotPoints->200]
```

[image: SmoothDensityHistogram]

Clearly, the structure has vanished.  Is there a way to represent the data as a continuum, yet not lose the critical shape of the plot?  Increasing `PlotPoints` doesn't seem to help.

Edit:  Lowing the bandwidth helps a little, but there is still a lot of structure that isn't represented in the density plot.  It seems to stop changing at a bandwidth lower than 0.01, so I'll post the image at that value.

[image]

I tried all of the pre-defined kernel options along with bw in espec, and none of them seemed to make a difference.

**Edit**: Minimal working example [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1a-ofhh_moN_u95bq5nMlD3CxAuiMzScV/view?usp=sharing), or raw data [here](https://pastebin.com/raw/r5Aiq03E) and [here](https://pastebin.com/raw/7bvzMuQV).

Comment: I think the key word is "Smooth" and with apparent sharp boundaries, you're going to get "smooth".  Now...if there's some theory that says you have an overlay of two (or more) areas of say uniform density, then one could fit those two types separately and then add the two together which should get you sharper borders.  But if you just have the data with no information on source or where the boundaries might be, then you're going to get something smoothed.

Comment: @JimB I don't see why "smooth" and "populated" need to be mutually exclusive.  I don't mind diffuse boarders, if that's what you mean by sharpness.  I think its pretty easy to look at the scatter plot and envision a smoother representation of the data which still preserves the 3 main features - a "diamond" in the center, two "arms" on the right, and some sort of "wedge" or "wake" on the left.  In the SmoothDensityHistogram, only the "diamond" structure is preserved at all from the data, and even that is sketchy.  Maybe I'm trying to use the wrong kind of plot?

Comment: Can you share the data?

Comment: Your minimal working example is not working for me.

Comment: @Rahul Sorry, fixed it.  Here's the new link. 
 https://drive.google.com/file/d/1a-ofhh_moN_u95bq5nMlD3CxAuiMzScV/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Sorry, I have to leave for a while but you should edit the link into your question so others can see it easily. And maybe un-accept the existing answer if you're not satisfied with the solution.

Comment: I wonder if this might explain the situation.  Our eye/brain conglomerate sees borders and shapes but `SmoothDensityHistogram` looks at shading by density of data which are two different viewpoints in this case.  The borders we see are not at a constant density but rather the density of points varies from high to much lower as one traverses a border.  So contours of constant density will not follow the borders.  Just like looking at a mountain top, we can "see" the ridge line but a contour/density plot won't have a "line" were we clearly see a ridge line.

Comment: One of the issues is that a fit with a constant bandwidth is being used on a larger set of points that what you show.  When just using the subset of points you show, `SmoothDensityHistogram` does a much better job.  The "theoretical" solution might be to use an adaptive kernel (which has smaller kernels in denser areas) but I haven't got that option to finish (but I only waited about 20 minutes before I killed it).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use the bandwidth option for `SmoothDensityHistogram` (where you have `Automatic`).

First generate some data (and I've literally stolen this from @ybeltukov in [MathematicaStackExchange: Generate random points in a region...](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/40595/generate-random-points-in-a-region-with-higher-probability-in-a-sub-region)):

```
n = 10000000;
r2 = 0.1;
choise = RandomChoice[{\[Pi] r2, 1} -> {0, 1}, n];
box = RandomReal[1, {n, 2}];
circle = Transpose@{0.5 + # Cos@#2, 0.5 + # Sin@#2} &[
   Sqrt@RandomReal[r2, n], RandomReal[2 \[Pi], n]];
pts = box choise + circle (1 - choise);
```

Plot data and `SmoothDensityHistogram` at various bandwidths:

```
Grid[{{ListPlot[pts[[;; ;; 300]], AspectRatio -> Automatic, 
    PlotLabel -> "Data"],
   SmoothDensityHistogram[pts[[;; ;; 300]], Automatic, 
    PlotRange -> {{0, 1}, {0, 1}},
    PlotLabel -> "Bandwidth = Automatic"]},
  {SmoothDensityHistogram[pts[[;; ;; 300]], .1, 
    PlotRange -> {{0, 1}, {0, 1}},
    PlotLabel -> "Bandwidth = 0.1"],
   SmoothDensityHistogram[pts[[;; ;; 300]], .02, 
    PlotRange -> {{0, 1}, {0, 1}},
    PlotLabel -> "Bandwidth=0.02"]}}]
```

[image: Data and various bandwidths]

***Update:***

One of the reasons for a poor representation is that what is shown above is just a small portion of the complete data set.  Having a single bandwidth with the complexity of the data (multiple peaks, multiple voids, etc.) is not likely to reproduce the pattern seen in the points.  Here is a figure showing all of the data and the red box delineates the subset shown above:

```
ListPlot[{V2aGrid, {{33, -2}, {33, 2}, {37, 2}, {37, -2}, {33, -2}}}, 
 ImageSize -> Medium, PlotRange -> All, PlotRangePadding -> None, Joined -> {False, True}, 
 AspectRatio -> 1, PlotStyle -> {Darker[Blue], {Thickness[0.01], Red}},
 PlotRangeClipping -> False]
```

[image: Complete dataset]

An alternative approach is to use an "adaptive" kernel which increases in size in low density areas and decreases in size in high density areas.  `SmoothDensityHistogram` offers this but with the number of points for this example, it did not complete after 20 minutes.

But if one just looks at the subset of data shown above, then a better match with the data points is achieved.  And here I use `SmoothKernelDistribution` followed by a `ContourPlot` to have a bit more control (i.e., convenient manipulation):

```
V2aGrid = Select[V2aGrid, -2 < #[[2]] < 2 &];
ListPlot[V2aGrid, ImageSize -> Medium, PlotRangePadding -> None]
skd = SmoothKernelDistribution[V2aGrid, 0.075];
ContourPlot[(1 - PDF[skd, {z, x}])^10, {z, 33, 37}, {x, -2, 2}, 
 PlotRange -> All,
 PlotPoints -> 100, ColorFunction -> "AvocadoColors", Contours -> 30,
 AspectRatio -> 0.65, ContourShading -> True, ContourStyle -> None]
```

[image: Data subset]

[image: SmoothKernel distribution on data subset]

I used `(1 - PDF[skd, {z, x}])^10` rather than `PDF[skd, {z, x}]` to separate the colors to better match the figure with the data points.

***2nd update:***

Rather than messing with the `PDF` it's probably better to do a bit of rescaling of the `"AvocadoColors"` (again using a subset of the complete dataset):

```
data = Select[V2aGrid, -2 < #[[2]] < 2 &];
SmoothDensityHistogram[data, 0.05, "PDF",
 ColorFunction -> Function[x, ColorData["AvocadoColors"][x^0.5]],
 PlotRangePadding -> None, AspectRatio -> 0.65,
 PlotRange -> All]
```

[image: SmoothDensityHistogram with color scaling]

And here's the whole dataset:

```
SmoothDensityHistogram[V2aGrid, Automatic, "PDF", 
 InterpolationPoints -> 200,
 ColorFunction -> Function[x, ColorData["AvocadoColors"][x^0.5]],
 PlotRangePadding -> None, AspectRatio -> 0.65,
 PlotRange -> All, PlotPoints -> 200]
```

[image: Complete dataset figure]

So some of the issue seems to be that the color scheme needs a bit of rescaling to show the detail.

Comment: Thanks.  I have edited the OP to reflect trying to modify the bw.  It helps, but doesn't really recover the structure apparent in the scatter plot.  Any additional ideas?

Comment: Seems like you pretty much nailed it.  Thanks!  I have accepted this answer.