# Values corresponding to SmoothDensityHistogram

Tags: probability-or-statistics, histograms

I am looking for extracting the values associated with SmoothDensityHistogram.

For example in

```
n = 100000;
r2 = 0.1;
choise = RandomChoice[{\[Pi] r2, 1} -> {0, 1}, n];
box = RandomReal[1, {n, 2}];
circle = Transpose@{0.5 + # Cos@#2, 0.5 + # Sin@#2} &[
Sqrt@RandomReal[r2, n], RandomReal[2 \[Pi], n]];
pts = box choise + circle (1 - choise);
```

(from [Generate random points in a region with higher probability in a sub-region](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/40595/generate-random-points-in-a-region-with-higher-probability-in-a-sub-region))

How can I extract the {x, y, z} values used to plot the

```
SmoothDensityHistogram[pts]
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You can use `SmoothKernelDistribution` with `pts` and extract the properties `"InterpolationPoints"` and `"PDFValues"` and combine them:

```
skd = SmoothKernelDistribution[pts]

xyz = Join[Tuples[skd["InterpolationPoints"]], List /@ skd["PDFValues"], 2];


Row[{Labeled[SmoothDensityHistogram[pts, PlotRange -> All, ImageSize -> 300], 
   "SmoothDensityHistogram[pts]", Top], 
  Labeled[ListDensityPlot[xyz, PlotRange -> All, ImageSize -> 300], 
   "ListDensityPlot[xyz]", Top]}, Spacer[10]]
```

[image]