# Random reals according to conditions

Tags: random

I'd like to create a list of triplets $(x,y,z)$ which satisfy the following properties: 
$$0<x<1/2 \\ 0<y<1/2-x \\ -1<z<-2(x+y)$$ Basically I would like to uniformly generate random points inside a pyramid which is what these inequalities represent. I'm not sure how to place these restrictions on the RandomReal command or how to tell *Mathematica* to exclude points that do not satisfy these conditions. Any help?

Thank you.

Comment: Related: [(13038)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/13038), [(32501)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/32501), [(33652)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/33652)

Comment: @Mr.Wizard It seems pretty close to a duplicate of 33652 -- see my answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following seems to work:

```
Cases[RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {1500000, 3}], {x_, y_, z_} /; 
  0 < x < 0.5 && 0 < y < 0.5 - x && -1 < z < -2 (x + y)]
```

OR

```
Select[RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {1500000, 3}], 
 0 < #[[1]] < 0.5 && 0 < #[[2]] < 0.5 - #[[1]] && -1 < #[[3]] < -2 (#[[1]] + #[[2]]) &]
```

Here is what it looks like:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: I believe that generation and filtering is a fine approach when the selection percentage is relatively high as is the case here. +1

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Thanks. I thought about a different approach but this seems to do the job in this case.

Comment: See links above for advanced methods for this class of problem.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard. Thanks, I actually voted in 2 out of the 3 links you provided. Just forgot about those.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I think it should be pointed out that about 0.5% of the points will be selected.  RunnyKine, it would more efficient to use separate `RandomReal` calls for each coordinate, transpose, and select.  The expected yield would be 1/6 or about 17%.

Comment: @MichaelE2 I missed that and assumed the larger figure.  Good catch.

Answer (score 5):

[Ray Koopman's](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/8159/ray-koopman) answer to [Uniformly distributed n-dimensional probability vectors over a simplex](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/33652/uniformly-distributed-n-dimensional-probability-vectors) applied to a simplex with given `vertices` leads to the following way to get (exactly) `n` uniformly distributed random points in the simplex (and do it quickly):

```
pts = #.vertices/Total[#, {2}] &@ Log @ RandomReal[1, {n, 4}];
```

Here are 2000 points in the OP's simplex:

```
vertices = Append[
  {x, y, z} /. 
     Last@Maximize[{#, 
         0 < x < 1/2 && 0 < y < 1/2 (1 - 2 x) && -1 < z < -2 x - 2 y} /. 
        Less -> LessEqual, {x, y, z}] & /@ {x, y, -z},
  {0, 0, 0}
  ]
(* {{1/2, 0, -1}, {0, 1/2, -1}, {0, 0, -1}, {0, 0, 0}} *)

pts = #.vertices/Total[#, {2}] &@ Log @ RandomReal[1, {2000, 4}];

Graphics3D[Point[pts], Axes -> True, 
 PlotRange -> {{0, 1/2}, {0, 1/2}, {-1, 0}}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: I think this is a good extension of the linked question rather than a duplicate. +1

Answer (score 5):

You can use [`RandomPoint`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RandomPoint) with [`ImplicitRegion`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ImplicitRegion):

```
RandomPoint[
    ImplicitRegion[0<x<1/2 && 0<y<1/2 && -1<z<-2(x+y), {x,y,z}],
    10
]
```

> {{0.0644104, 0.289938, -0.812196}, {0.162676, 0.0447583, -0.805135}, {0.29663,
>      0.0801703, -0.955995}, {0.0845065, 0.0982267, -0.542481}, {0.00591773, 
>     0.0586124, -0.222642}, {0.395283, 0.0611798, -0.965819}, {0.281329, 
>     0.0247549, -0.985743}, {0.0997621, 0.156397, -0.969405}, {0.136775, 
>     0.176456, -0.934246}, {0.165527, 0.234188, -0.836819}}

Or, if you know the corners of the tetrahedron, you could use:

```
RandomPoint[
    Tetrahedron[{{0,0,-1},{0,1/2,-1},{1/2,0,-1},{0,0,0}}],
    10
]
```

> {{0.103469, 0.00460676, -0.804016}, {0.155514, 
>     0.266517, -0.934628}, {0.0258173, 0.0425049, -0.344449}, {0.161183, 
>     0.0999294, -0.639421}, {0.124769, 0.194545, -0.914526}, {0.223348, 
>     0.08202, -0.620869}, {0.0379937, 0.0701453, -0.401479}, {0.0608969, 
>     0.0313861, -0.458453}, {0.00207286, 0.136834, -0.477351}, {0.246812, 
>     0.0634065, -0.89431}}