# How to draw a 3D quaternary phase diagram

Tags: graphics3d, input

I tried many software however no one worked. I knew someone drew a tetrahedron using Mathematica. [Extending a ternary plot to a tetrahedron (using ListPlot)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/57432/extending-a-ternary-plot-to-a-tetrahedron-using-listplot)
However, I'm just starting to use Mathematica,   I don't know how to input data in the tetrahedron. I want to draw a quaternary phase diagram as shown below. I appreciate it if it could be solved. Thanks so much

[image: quaternary phase diagram]

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise. 2) Take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour)! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://i.stack.imgur.com/eNrdG.png), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, by [clicking the checkmark sign](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/)!

Comment: Someone might have such an example lying around, I suppose, but the rest of us might appreciate some data, an equation for the surface, and any other information (such as what the dotted lines are) that would help us formulate an answer.  Preferably in valid *Mathematica* syntax.