# Finding uniformly distributed random points on an ellipsoid

Tags: random

I am trying to generate a poincare map for a system whose reduced energy manifold looks like the following surface.

```
(x/a)^2 +(y/b)^2 +(z/c)^2=1
```

I want to find a lot of sample points(initial conditions) on the above mentioned ellipsoid.

Can anyone suggest a nice elegant way of doing this?

So far I have tried the following

```
a1[y_] := R Sqrt[Energy (1 - y^2/Energy)];
a2[vy_, y_] := Sqrt[2 Energy (1 - (vy^2/(Energy*R^2) + y^2/Energy))]
y1 = Table[i, {i, -Sqrt[Energy], Sqrt[Energy], inc}]
vyi = Map[a1, y1];
vyf = Flatten[Range[0, vyi, (vyi - 0)/num]];
yf = Flatten[Table[#, {num + 1}] & /@ y1];
vx1 = Re[a2[a, b] /. {a -> vyf, b -> yf}]
IC = Table[{vx1[[i]], yf[[i]], vyf[[i]]}, {i, 1, (num + 1)^2}]
```

where a=2*Energy,b=2*Energy*R^2 and c=Energy. (vx1,yf,vyf) represents (x,y,z)

Excuse me if this sounds a very basic question, but I am new to mathematica. I am trying to learn through the documentation but I could not get a good reference on how to go about this problem.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest that: 1) You take the introductory [Tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) now! 2) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)! 3) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise.

Comment: Please provide sample code that you are using.

Comment: What does this question have to do with "zeros"?  Is your question instead:  "How do I randomly choose points from the surface of an ellipsoid?"

Comment: @DavidG.Stork: Yes sir, I want to know a way to find out uniformly distributed random points on the surface of an ellipsoid. Kindly excuse me for the error.

Comment: See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/973101/how-to-generate-points-uniformly-distributed-on-the-surface-of-an-ellipsoid

Comment: This and more: [32501](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/32501/5478)

Comment: @Kuba `RandomPoint` is really a killer feature of v10.2 for uniform sampling on geometric regions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood you right, there is a function returning n uniformly distributed random numbers lying on the ellipsoid with the surface you have specified:

```
        lst[a_, b_, c_, n_] := 
  Select[MapThread[{#1, #2, 
      c*RandomChoice[{-1, 1}]*
       Sqrt[1 - (#1/a)^2 - (#2/b)^2]} &, {RandomReal[{-a, a}, n], 
     RandomReal[{-b, b}, n]}], #[[3]] \[Element] Reals &];
```

This draws the image along with the ellipsoid in question:

```
 pl[a_, b_, c_, n_] := Show[{
    Graphics3D[Point[#] & /@ lst[a, b, c, n]],
    Graphics3D[{Opacity[0.5], Ellipsoid[{0, 0, 0}, {a, b, c}]}]
    }];
```

Let us draw them and check that they are indeed where we want them. I will choose the ellipsoid with the semi-axes 1,2 and 0.5:

```
pl[1, 2, 0.5, 500]
```

It should look as follows:

[image]

Have fun!

Comment: Thank you so much..! It helped..!!

Answer (score 4):

You could also use this pl2 function, which does in fact distribute the points uniformly, unlike the pl function from the other answer:

```
lst[a_, b_, c_, n_] := Select[MapThread[{#1, #2, c RandomChoice[{-1, 1}]
  Sqrt[1 - (#1/a)^2 - (#2/b)^2]} &, {RandomReal[{-a, a}, n], 
  RandomReal[{-b, b}, n]}], #[[3]] \[Element] Reals &];

pl[a_, b_, c_, n_, v_] := Show[{Graphics3D[Point[#] & /@ lst[a, b, c, n]],
  Graphics3D[{Opacity[0.5], Ellipsoid[{0, 0, 0}, {a, b, c}]}]},
  Axes -> True, AspectRatio -> Automatic, ViewPoint -> v, ImageSize -> 250];

pl2[a_, b_, c_, n_, v_] := With[{L = RandomVariate[MultinormalDistribution[{0, 0, 0},
  DiagonalMatrix[{##}]], n]}, Show[Graphics3D[Thread[Point[(a b c)/Sqrt[(L L).{#2 #3,
  # #3, # #2}] L]]], Graphics3D[{Opacity[0.5], Ellipsoid[{0, 0, 0}, {a, b, c}]}],
  Axes -> True, AspectRatio -> Automatic, ViewPoint -> v, ImageSize -> 250]] &[a^2, b^2, c^2]

a = 3; b = 1; c = 1;
Grid[{{pl[a, b, c, #, Front], pl[a, b, c, #, Top]},
  {pl2[a, b, c, #, Front], pl2[a, b, c, #, Top]}}] &[2500]
```

[image]

With `b == c` the top and front view should be the "same"!

Comment: how can you access the coordinates of the generated points?