# Density plot with dots

Tags: plotting, plot-themes

I want to plot an arbitrary 2D function, for example $ e ^ { -(x^2+y^2) } $. The plot should contain dots, the density of dots at a point indicating the value of the function at that point.

The output should be something like this:
[image: Sample plot]

How to do it?

Comment: This topic is slightly different but one of answers fully answer a general case: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/32540/5478

Answer (score 2):

You could use [`RandomVariate`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RandomVariate) on a [`BinormalDistribution`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/BinormalDistribution):

```
dist = BinormalDistribution[{0,0}, {1,1}/Sqrt[2], 0];
```

Check the pdf:

```
PDF[dist, {x,y}] //Simplify
```

> E^(-x^2 - y^2)/π

Up to normalization, it is the same as your function. Then, we can generate some random points and plot:

```
Graphics[{
    Opacity[.05],
    Point @ RandomVariate[dist, 10^5]
}]
```

[image]

Comment: OP seems to want an arbitrary function.

Comment: I think you could use a Metropolis-sampling type algorithm to generate this for arbitrary functions (since basically we're doing a numerical approximation of the function but with delta functions) but I'm not expert enough to quickly vomit one of those out.

Comment: @b3m2a1 done I guess: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/32540/5478

Comment: @Kuba good find! I'll definitely have to keep that one in mind. And if you look at like fig. 3 from that answer it's exactly what the OP wants.

Comment: @b3m2a1 yep, that was my point :)

Comment: @b3m2a1 and Carl, I am not sure what should I do. Clearly ybeltukov crossed the line by posting too general answer! :) It is not an exact duplicate but 'this is answerd in ..' description fits. I'd close it then and leave it as a roadsign. Or? CW answer with ybeltukov's Metropolis?

Comment: I'd do the latter. It's worth keeping this open as it's not a dupe *question* and other people might have other ideas. So I think CW-ing ybeltukov's answer (with a link of course) is the way to go.

Comment: @Kuba Sounds like a duplicate to me. Could reopen if the OP adds details explaining why the other answer doesn't apply.