# Poisson PDE over a irregular region with FDM

Tags: differential-equations, difference-equations, finite-difference-method

The problem modeled by the Poisson PDE is related to the torsion of prismatic beams and I use the Finite Differences Method (FDM). I've managed to solve the equation over a rectangle region with quadratic mesh, here's my code (the dimensions are 0.2 m × 0.2 m):

```
a = 0.2;
b = 0.2;
n = 4;
m = 4;
deltax = a/n;
deltay = b/m;
G = 10^6;
theta = 0.01745;
phi[0, j_] = 0;
phi[n, j_] = 0;
phi[i_, 0] = 0;
phi[i_, m] = 0;
fi[i_, j_] = -2 G theta;
vars = Flatten[Table[phi[i, j], {i, 1, n - 1}, {j, 1, m - 1}]];
eqns = Flatten[
Table[(phi[i + 1, j] - 2 phi[i, j] + phi[i - 1, j])/
   deltax^2 + (phi[i, j + 1] - 2 phi[i, j] + phi[i, j - 1])/
   deltay^2 == fi[i, j], {i, 1, n - 1}, {j, 1, m - 1}]];
sol = Solve[eqns, vars][[1]]
```

But I also need to solve for a circular region with radius 0.1m, and I frankly don't have an idea what to do:

[image]

The corresponding difference equation is:

$\frac{2}{\Delta x^{2}}\left(\frac{1}{a(1+a)}\phi_{i-1,j}+\frac{1}{1+a}\phi_{i+1,j}-\frac{1}{a}\phi_{i,j}\right)+\frac{2}{\Delta y^{2}}\left(\frac{1}{b(1+b)}\phi_{i,j-1}+\frac{1}{1+b}\phi_{i,j+1}-\frac{1}{b}\phi_{i,j}\right)=-2G\theta$

I know how to solve it with `NDSolve`:

```
R = 0.1;
G = 1000000;
θ = 0.01745329252;
Ω = Disk[{0, 0}, {R, R}];
op = Laplacian[u[x, y], {x, y}] +2 G θ;
Subscript[Γ,D] = {DirichletCondition[u[x, y] == 0, True]};
Φ = 
NDSolveValue[{op == 0, Subscript[Γ, D]}, u, {x, y} ∈ Ω];

Plot3D[Φ[x, y], {x, y} ∈ Ω]
```

[image]

I just want to solve the problem with FDM using Cartesian coordinates.

Comment: No worries :)   .

Comment: Well, is it necessary for you to use FDM rather than `NDSolve` solving this equation? To say at least, is it necessary for you to use Cartesian form of the equation rather than polar form? The handling for irregular mesh in FDM is really cumbersome in my view, in fact that's where I stoped my self-learning for FDM. (You may be interested [in this post](http://scicomp.stackexchange.com/q/10187/5331). )

Comment: Yes, because I want to solve the problem with FDM, the solution with NDSolve already I have.

Comment: @wlkyr So the polar form isn't what you need either and you simply want to explore FDM for irregular region?

Comment: Yes, because I want to solve with Cartesian form, and I find the solution numericali but I dont have idea how to solve with Mathematica

Comment: Well, if you don't add @xzczd in your comment, I won't get the reminder. BTW, your new-added code is messy (and in fact broken), please press Ctrl+Shift+I to change it into `InputForm` before pasting it here.

Comment: This post is closely related: [Poisson solver using Mathematica](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/11763/245) I would have marked your post as a duplicate of the linked question, but didn't see this post until now.

Comment: @xzczd hawe you any idea for sloving this problem with polar coordinates?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As mentioned in the comment above, handling irregular region with FDM is cumbersome and frustrating in my view, actually that's where I stopped my self-learning of FDM and turned to finite element method (FEM), which is more suitable for this task, and finally write [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/44085/1871). (Have a look at [this post](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/q/10187/5331) for more information. ) Nevertheless, there seems to be no implementation of FDM on irregular region with *Mathematica* hitherto, so I'd like to have a try.

Well, I believe that as a centuried technique, there must be some legacy code (probably in other programming language) implementing FDM on irregular region, but strangely I never found a piece. (My skill of googling is too bad?) So the following code is completely self-made and quite Mathematica-style (I think).

The method I chose to treat the irregular boundary is the one OP mentioned in his question: extrapolation. Yeah, that graph and the difference equation illustrates extrapolation. If you're unfamiliar with it, a relatively good learning material is *Section 3.4* from p71 and *Section 6.4* from p199 of [Numerical Solution of Partial Differential Equations - An Introduction (Morton K., Mayers D)](http://math.science.cmu.ac.th/docs/qNA2556/ref_na/Morton_Numerical%20Solution%20of%20PDE.pdf)… OK, let me explain it briefly.

***Graph 1***

[image]

*Red points for the unknowns, gray points for those outside the domain, values on green curve is known.*

FDM is a technique solving unknown grids with known grids, but as shown in ***Graph 1***, when implementing FDM on an irregular region, grid points are usually not exactly on the boundary where the function value is known, so what to do? The simplest solution is to treat the grids near the boundary as grids on the boundary, which is called zero-order interpolation and discouraged. (Those material I found doesn't mention the reason, I guess it's probably because the error caused by zero-order interpolation is large and not quantitatively controllable.) To achieve the quantitative control on the error caused by FDM, extrapolation is needed. For example, as illustrated in ***Graph 2*** below, we can use the values on **B**, **C**, **D** to fit a parabola to estimate the value on **A**:

***Graph 2***

[image]

An equivalent explanation for the extrapolation is weighted difference formula, which is also covered in the book linked above. In the rest part of this answer I'll concentrate on programming. Here's the code:

```
G = 1000000;
θ = Rationalize[0.01745329252, 0];
m = n = 24;
R = 1/10;
dx = 2 R/m; dy = 2 R/n;

r1 = Solve[(x + R)/dx == i, x][[1]];
r2 = Solve[(y + R)/dy == j, y][[1]];
ruleInner = (x^2 + y^2 < R^2 /. r1 /. r2);
ruleOuter = (x^2 + y^2 > R^2 /. r1 /. r2);
areaInner = Table[ruleInner, {i, 0, m}, {j, 0, n}];
areaOuter = Table[ruleOuter, {i, 0, m}, {j, 0, n}];

ArrayPlot /@ Boole[{areaInner, areaOuter}]
```

[image]

I rationalized all the parameters for convenience. `areaInner` and `areaOuter` are masks for extracting the desired grid points:

```
{var, varNot} = 
  Flatten@Pick[Table[f[i, j], {i, 0, m}, {j, 0, n}], #] & /@ {areaInner, areaOuter};
```

`var` are grid points inside the circle i.e. the red points in ***Graph 1***, `varNot` are the grays.

```
df[dx_, pos_] := (MapAt[# - 1 &, #, pos] - 2 # + MapAt[# + 1 &, #, pos])/dx^2 &
{d2fx, d2fy} = {df[dx, 1] /@ var, df[dy, 2] /@ var};
```

`d2fx` and `d2fy` are $\frac{\partial ^2\phi }{\partial x^2}$ and $\frac{\partial ^2\phi }{\partial y^2}$.

```
{d2fxOuter, d2fyOuter} = 
  Intersection[varNot, Cases[#, f[__], Infinity]] & /@ {d2fx, d2fy};
{d2fxBorder, d2fyBorder} = 
  Thread[Complement[Cases[#, f[__], Infinity], var, varNot] -> 0] & /@ {d2fx, d2fy};
```

`d2fxOuter` and `d2fyOuter` are grids outside the region but appearing in the equations i.e. **A**s in ***Graph 2***, `d2fxBorder` and `d2fyBorder` are those exactly on the boundaries, where **A**s and **B**s superpose. (It is relatively rare, actually there're only 4 in this case). Then we use extrapolation to approximate those outside the region:

```
{pointBorderd2fx, pointBorderd2fy} = 
  With[{ex = #[[1]], pos = #[[2]]}, 
     With[{pos2 = 2 - pos + 1}, {#, 0} & /@ 
       Flatten[Nearest[{i, j}[[pos]] /. 
             Solve[x^2 + y^2 == R^2 /. r1 /. r2, {i, j}[[pos]]] /. {i,
                j}[[pos2]] -> #[[pos2]], #[[pos]]] & /@ ex]]] & /@ 
{{d2fxOuter, 1}, {d2fyOuter, 2}};
```

`pointBorderd2fx` and `pointBorderd2fy` are points on the boundary that will be used in extrapolation i.e.  **B**s in ***Graph 2***.

```
{pointInnerd2fx, pointInnerd2fy} = 
  With[{ex = #[[1]], pos = #[[2]]}, 
     Map[{#[[pos]], #} &, 
      Intersection[#, var] & /@ 
       Thread /@ 
        MapAt[{-2, -1, 1, 2} + # &, ex, {All, pos}], {2}]] & /@ 
{{d2fxOuter, 1}, {d2fyOuter, 2}};
```

`pointInnerd2fx` and `pointInnerd2fy` are points inside the domain that will be used in extrapolation i.e. **C**s and **D**s in ***Graph 2***.

```
extra[{x4_, y4_}, {x1_, y1_}, {{x2_, y2_}, {x3_, y3_}}] = 
  y4 -> InterpolatingPolynomial[{{x1, y1}, {x2, y2}, {x3, y3}}, x4];
```

`extra` provides the **extra**polating formula. The last step is to form the equation set with difference equations, eliminating **A**s with **B**s, **C**s and **D**s and then **sol**ve it:

```
sol = First@
    NSolve[(d2fx /. d2fxBorder /. MapThread[extra, {{#[[1]], #} & /@ d2fxOuter, 
                                                   pointBorderd2fx, 
                                                   pointInnerd2fx}]) + 
           (d2fy /. d2fyBorder /. MapThread[extra, {{#[[2]], #} & /@ d2fyOuter, 
                                                   pointBorderd2fy, 
                                                   pointInnerd2fy}]) == 
           -2 G θ // Thread, var]; // AbsoluteTiming
```

Finally let's draw a picture for the solution. Notice that we need to add points on the **bound**ary because they are almost not included in `sol`:

```
bound = Flatten /@ Transpose@{#, ConstantArray[0., Length@#]} &@
   Cases[Normal@
      ContourPlot[
       x^2 + y^2 == R^2 /. r1 /. r2 // Evaluate, {i, 0, m}, {j, 0, n}], 
         Line[a__] -> a, ∞][[1]];

ListPlot3D[Join[bound, sol /. (f[a_, b_] -> c_) :> {a, b, c}]]
```

[image]

Comment: Useful post. Any reference/idea on how to apply extrapolation at a corner node in a 9-point compact stencil discretizing the anisotropic diffusion operator on non-rectangular domain with non-uniform grid?

Comment: @unlikely Glad it help. As mentioned, this post is my first trial for FDM on irregular region, and in fact all the references in my hand has been linked in this post, maybe you can consider asking a separate question for your specific equation?

Comment: Thanks for help, but I have another question how to solve same example in polar coordinates?please help me

Comment: Thanks Jens, I try that in polar coordinates but I have a problem with boundary values. I posted that http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/78468/boundary-value-problem-with-fdm-in-poisson-pde

Comment: @xzczd Thanks for the answer, but I have another question with your programs, when I changed m and n the radius of circle changed

Comment: @wlkyr It's just because I didn't use the original coordinate. Map it back if you like.