# Laplace equation in a gapped rectangular domain with finite difference method

Tags: differential-equations, finite-difference-method

I have a situation that is shown by this picture:

[image: situation 1]

For this situation I have this code.

```
Clear["Global`*"]
nx = 40; ny = 20;
Do[h[i, -1] = h[i, 1], {i, 0, nx}]
Do[h[nx + 1, j] = h[nx - 1, j], {j, 0, ny}]
Do[h[i, ny] = 10, {i, 0, nx/2}]
Do[h[i, ny] = 1, {i, nx/2 + 1, nx}]
Do[h[-1, j] = h[1, j], {j, 0, ny}]
Do[eq[i, j] = h[i - 1, j] + h[i + 1, j] + h[i, j - 1] + h[i, j + 1] - 4h[i, j] == 0., {i, 0, nx}, {j, 0, ny}]
sol = Solve[Flatten[Table[eq[i, j], {i, 0, nx}, {j, 0, ny}]]];
Do[h[i, j] = h[i, j] /. sol[[1]], {i, 0, nx}, {j, 0, ny}];
h1 = Interpolation[Flatten[Table[{{x, y}, h[x, y]}, {x, 0, nx}, {y, 0, ny}], 1]];
Plot3D[h1[x, y], {x, 0, nx}, {y, 0, ny}]

hx = D[h1[x, y], x];
hy = D[h1[x, y], y];
StreamPlot[{-hx, -hy}, {x, 0, nx}, {y, 0, ny}]
```

However, now I have different situation as in this picture

[image: situation 2]

I need to modify the code I just wrote to describe this situation, so on that box ( 6 m by 3 m ) there is no flow

I would appreciate your help.

Comment: Well, I think this is problem is quite similar to the former, what trouble do you have?

Comment: I dont know what the necessary modifaction do I need to do on the code to get the new one.    I would apprecuate someone's help

Comment: Just figure out the meaning of the `selectedeq = Select[eq, Count[#, Alternatives @@ inner, Infinity] < 2 &];` line in [this answer](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/103442/1871) with the help of document, then you'll have an idea about what to do.

Comment: @xzczd I am sorry to bother you and and I apprecaite your help.   Actually I did not get the code you sent . Until now I have not figured a way to do it :(

Comment: Just press **F1** and check the document of every function in that code line. If you still don't know how to use document, check [this post](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/18606/1871). I can give an answer, but I'm afraid you won't understand it if you can't even figure out the meaning of the code line above.

Comment: @xzczd I would appreciate if you could solve it and I will try this night to go over it and fully understand it and tomorrow I will go with my proffesor after your code to explain to me the lines that I did not got. I am sorry again and your help will be highly appreciable.

Answer (score 4):

Here's my FDM-based solution for your problem:

```
{{xl, xr}, {yl, yr}} = {{0, 33}, {0, 15}};
sf = 2;
nx = sf xr; ny = sf yr;
dx = (xr - xl)/nx; dy = (yr - yl)/ny;
xmidl = 15; xmidr = 18; ymid = 9;
h1 = 14; h2 = 2;
formula = Select[
   Flatten@Table[
      h[x - dx, y] + h[x + dx, y] + h[x, y - dy] + h[x, y + dy] - 4 h[x, y] == 0, {x, xl,
        xr, dx}, {y, yl, yr, dy}][[2 ;; -2, 2 ;; -2]], 
   FreeQ[#, h[x_, y_] /; xmidl < x < xmidr && y > ymid] &];
oneSideD1[most__, "left"] := oneSideD1[most, -1]
oneSideD1[most__, "right"] := oneSideD1[most, 1]
oneSideD1[h_, x_, step_, direction : 1 | -1] := 
 direction ((3 h@x)/(2 step) - (2 h[x - direction step])/step + h[x - 2 direction step]/
    (2 step))
bcxl = Table[oneSideD1[h[#, y] &, xl, dx, "left"] == 0, {y, yl, yr, dy}][[2 ;; -2]];
bcxr = Table[oneSideD1[h[#, y] &, xr, dx, "right"] == 0, {y, yl, yr, dy}][[2 ;; -2]];
bcyl = Table[oneSideD1[h[x, #] &, yl, dy, "left"] == 0, {x, xl, xr, dx}];
bcyr@1 = Table[h[x, yr] == h1, {x, xl, xmidl, dx}];
bcyr@5 = Table[h[x, yr] == h2, {x, xmidr, xr, dx}];
bcyr@3 = Table[
    oneSideD1[h[x, #] &, ymid, dy, "right"] == 0, {x, xmidl, xmidr, dx}][[2 ;; -2]];
bcyr@2 = Table[
    oneSideD1[h[#, y] &, xmidl, dx, "right"] == 0, {y, ymid, yr, dy}][[2 ;; -2]];
bcyr@4 = Table[
    oneSideD1[h[#, y] &, xmidr, dx, "left"] == 0, {y, ymid, yr, dy}][[2 ;; -2]];
set = Flatten@{formula, bcxl, bcxr, bcyl, bcyr /@ Range@5};
var = Union@Cases[set, h[a_, b_], ∞];
{b, mat} = CoefficientArrays[set, var];
sol = LinearSolve[mat, -N@b];
coord = List @@@ var;
ListPointPlot3D[Flatten /@ ({coord, sol}\[Transpose]), PlotRange -> All]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

**Remark**

1. I've used one-sided difference formula i.e. `oneSideD1` to discretize the Neumann boundary condtions. For your simple Neumann b.c., it's not a bad idea to handle them with reflection of course, but do notice reflection is hard to extend to more general cases. (If you want to learn more about one-sided formula, start from page 6 of [this book](https://disciplinas.stoa.usp.br/pluginfile.php/41896/mod_resource/content/1/LeVeque%20Finite%20Diff.pdf). )
2. `sf` should be an `Integer`.
3. You can also use

   ```
   SetAttributes[h, NHoldAll]    
   sol2 = Solve[N@set, var]; // AbsoluteTiming
   ```

   to solve the equation set, but this approach is slower. (The speed difference isn't obvious in this simple case though.)

Comment: (+1) It works. Since the OP is just learning the ropes, let me just point out the valuable tutorial in the documentation on [The Numerical Method of Lines](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/NDSolveMethodOfLines.html). In particular, that page describes `FiniteDifferenceDerivative` which is a good way to obtain the matrices automatically.

Comment: @Jens Yeah, ``NDSolve`FiniteDifferenceDerivative`` is powerful. (I dug out the one-sided difference formula by observing ``NDSolve`FiniteDifferenceDerivative[1, #, f /@ #, DifferenceOrder -> 2] &@(d Range@5)`` actually. ) Sadly there seems to be no simple way to extend its usage to irregular regions.

Comment: I think there's something wrong with `oneSideD1` because the solution looks like it obeys Dirichlet conditions instead of Neumann.

Comment: @Jens You're right. I missed a `2` in the definition. Edited. Thx for pointing out.

Comment: Yes, now it looks right!